# Latin for phoenix quote

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

From the Cumberland Gazette, October 25, 1790, appears the following text about the seal of the city of Portland, Maine.

> It represents a phoenix rising from the ashes

I would like to set the text "a phoenix rising from the ashes" in Latin, to match the motto of Portland, which is *resurgam*.  The text will be used in a musical work.

Google translate gives several variations:

> phoenix de cinere ortu

> phoenix oritur ex cinere

> phoenix ex cineribus oritur

Is there one of these three translations that is preferred?  I am most interested in the idea of a people rising after adversity than the literal translation of a phoenix rising.

Relatedly, is the Latin *phoenix*, a two- or three-syllable word?

Comment: I think I would've preferred insurgere instead of oriri, so something like: `īnsurgit ē cinere`.

Comment: Why not use the same verb as in the motto, *resurgo*?

Comment: @Jacqueline being someone not terribly familiar with Latin, I would love for you to post an answer telling me why you prefer insurgere.

Comment: @TKR I would love it if you'd post your idea, and an explanation for a non-Latin scholar, as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To my experience, [oriri](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=lsn33000) is more than often used for events relating to time (e.g. unde oritur nox), and "astronomical bodies" (stars, the Sun, the Moon...); and when it is used for humans it means "to appear" or "to be born".

As TKR suggested in a comment under your question, "resurgere" can be used for your translation. Like in English, "re" usually gives an "again" meaning to verbs also in Latin.

Yet to my interpretation, since the Phoenix is something anew risen from ashes, and not ashes from a phoenix so it would not be "rising again" but more like "out of a downfall of something, something anew and more powerful rises", and thus I would use [insugere](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=lsn24072) in the same sense that Marcus Annaeus Lucanus used in [Bellum Civile](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/917/1/4/32069-32075@1#4), to say "rising into the sky" (caelum/caelus "the sky" can also refer to "the Heaven") "insurgere caelo".

Hence `īnsurgit ē cinere`. You might ask why the long `e` instead of `ex`: The long e `ē` was often used if the next word begins with a consonant and `ex` was used before a vowel - if for your musical reasons `ex` fits better in your work, I don't think it would be so wrong to use it.

In response to your syllable question: Since Phoenix is `phoenīx, phoenīcis, f.`, and since it is coming from Ancient Greek, I think that `oe` is a diphthong there - so two syllables.